# Split array into overlapping chunks (moving subgroups)

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, moving-average

There is a great question on how to [split a JavaScript array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks).  I'm currently using this for some statistical methods I'm writing and the [answer that I'm using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456644/984239) is as follows (although I chose not to extend the Array prototype like they did in the answer):

```
var chunk = function(array, chunkSize) {
    return [].concat.apply([],
        array.map(function(elem,i) {
            return i%chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i,i+chunkSize)];
        })
    );
};
```

This takes an array, such as `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, and given a `chunkSize` of 2 returns `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`.  I'm curious how I could modify this to create an array of "overlapping" chunks (or for those familiar with methods such as a moving average, "moving subgroups").

Provided the same array as above and `chunkSize` of 3, it would return `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]`.  A `chunkSize` of 2 would return `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]`.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function chunk (array, chunkSize) {
    var retArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - (chunkSize - 1); i++) {
        retArr.push(array.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    return retArr;
}
```

If you did want to extend the prototype (probably would be better) it would looks like this:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function( chunkSize ) {
    var retArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length - (chunkSize - 1); i++) {
        retArr.push( this.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    return retArr;
}
```

Comment: A couple things: first, you need to define `var array = this;` in order to use it in your for loop for the prototype extension.  Second, this is very close, but not quite.  Given `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, it returns `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]`.  Changing the max value for `i` from `array.length - chunkSize` to `array.length - chunkSize/2` fixed this problem though.  Thanks for this!

Comment: you are right on both accounts... Sorry i didnt spend very long proof reading my work

Comment: actually on second thought `array.length - chunkSize/2` wont work. I think you would want `array.length - (chunkSize - 1)`

Comment: Ack! Yup. Good catch (I was using chunk sizes of 2 to test...).  Thanks again!

Comment: ES6 version: `const movingSubgroups = ([...array], chunkSize = 2) => { chunkSize = Math.min(2 ** 32 - 1, Math.max(0, chunkSize)); return array.reduce((result, _element, index, currentArray) => { if(index <= currentArray.length - chunkSize){ result.push(currentArray.slice(index, index + chunkSize)); } return result; }, []); };`.

Comment: If you’re going to extend built-in prototypes or polyfill a property (i.e. monkey-patch), **please do it correctly**: for forward compatibility, check if the property exists _first_, then make the property non-enumerable so that the own keys of constructed objects aren’t polluted. For methods, use _actual_ [methods](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). My recommendation: follow [these examples](/a/46491279/4642212) which demonstrate how to add a method that behaves like other built-in methods, as closely as possible.

Comment: @SebastianSimon You are correct. There is now a much better way to do this. For the record, when I wrote this answer in 2013 (*8 years ago*), much of what you are suggesting was not fully supported. That or I was afraid to use it because either it -- 
 or possibly I -- was too green. This is why it was not part of my answer. The better advice here is to look at the age of the answer you find when googling the answer and be aware that things change over time in my humble opinion.

Comment: @gbtimmon I’m fully aware of the age of this answer. That comment isn’t for you specifically; it’s for any future reader who considers using this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the more declarative and consise (IMO) aproach.

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function getGroups(dataList, groupSize) {
  return dataList
    .slice(groupSize - 1)
    .map((_, index) => dataList.slice(index, index + groupSize));
}
console.log("2:", JSON.stringify(getGroups(data, 2)));
console.log("3:", JSON.stringify(getGroups(data, 3)));
```

Firstly I remove the number of elements from the start of the array since number of elements in the output will be appropriately smaller. Then i loop over the remaining elements mapping them to appropriate groups.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really good with javaScript but this is algorithmically very easy to achieve with two nested for loops. Here is a solution in C# - you should be able to figure this out quite easily.

This used less than optimal data structures and everything but the algorithm itself is obvious.

```
protected List<List<int>> Split(List<int> array, int chunkSize)
{
    List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count - chunkSize; i++)
    {
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();
        for (int j = i; j < i + chunkSize; j++)
        {
            temp.Add(array[j]);
        }
        result.Add(temp);
    }

    return result;
}
```